# How to run docker images File in window 8?

Tags: docker

I'm using docker version 1.9.1 running on Window 8 64-bit.
I'm import images(.tar) file from local machine to docker.I running the following command for to run import images file.

$docker images

REPOSITORY        TAG                  IMAGE ID                  CREATED
VIRTUAL SIZE
containerName     Latest               9298fcd17da9            22minutes ago

$docker run -i -t containerName

Error response from daemon: No command specified

How can i explain?
How can start docker images?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to start an interactive shell in the container, you need to specify a command after the container name. You probably have bash:

```
docker exec -it containerName /bin/bash
```

Comment: I want to run image and i want to see Kitematic .I found Error: response from deamo:no such id:

Comment: You may have built a container named `containerName`, but what was the source Docker image used to create that container?